# Sockets (SignalR) vs Push notifications

Tags: android, ios, concepts, xamarin

I'm developing a Xamarin.Forms app with a .Net Web API backend. I definitely don't want to do long polls on my app to the server, but I need the app to remain updated with the server information.

I thought push notifications were the solution (I even started developing that way), until I saw several examples using it only for messages. Is this so? Can I use push notifications only to send messages to the user's phone?

I already use SignalR in my application (I also have a MVC frontend) and I just found out I can use a SignalR client within my Xamarin.Forms app.

Is this the right way to go?

How do I maintain my app's data updated without long polling?

Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "right?"

Comment: What is a notification if not a message sent from the server to the client?

Comment: @RubberDuck ok, but from what I saw I thought push notifications were only intended to send messages to the users, am I wrong? could I use it as a way to update my app without breaking any standards?

Comment: @RobertHarvey just from a standard point of view. Like, would I be breaking any standards by using any of the methods? What is the technology people use to handle this issue regularly? Thanks.

Comment: As you've already pointed out, push notifications are typically used for app messages.  SignalR is used for general real-time communication.  As far as standards go, SignalR uses standard websockets, and falls back to older technologies for web browsers that don't support websockets.  I have no idea what push notifications uses.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, as I said I already use SignalR and understand the way it works, but I'd like to ask you if using it on a mobile application would be ok. Would you know if that's something recommended? (That's what I mean by right, I guess :D. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean by "ok?"

Comment: @RobertHarvey Would you know if that's something recommended?

Comment: A Google Search for "real-time communication with xamarin" yields [this article](http://developer.telerik.com/products/real-time-mobile-apps-with-appbuilder-xamarin-and-signalr/) as the first search result.

Comment: i think it depends. if you're writing a chat application, where one second delay is unacceptable, you should use `SignalR`. if not, create a task that will be [run on the background](http://arteksoftware.com/backgrounding-with-xamarin-forms/) with the desired rate, make an HTTP request in it. then use [push notifications](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/) to communicate with the user.